# Splitting string into multiple words

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have multiple stock names as follows

```
'ADANIENT29APR211120'
'AARTIIND29APR211360'
'ADANIPORTS29APR21730'
```

What I intend to do is to seperate the stock name, date, the price and print it as shown

```
'ADANIENT 29APR21 1120'
'AARTIIND 29APR21 1360'
'ADANIPORTS 29APR21 730'
```

Now i know about  module known as datefinder which can help me to extract dates in python

I used it as follows:

```
import datefinder

string_with_dates = '''
    ADANIENT29APR211120PE
'''

matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

The output this gives me is

```
runfile('C:/Users/hozef/AppData/Local/Temp/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/hozef/AppData/Local/Temp')
2021-04-29 21:11:20
```

My question is that using datefinder I extracted the date in the string now how do i extract the name and price of the particular stock from the input string

Comment: It is easy if you define constraints for your input. If you set a constraint that your stock symbol can not contain numbers, you can apply a regex or even break based on the position of numbers and create separate fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = ['ADANIENT29APR211120', 'AARTIIND29APR211360', 'ADANIPORTS29APR21730']
for x in inp:
    parts = re.findall(r'^([A-Z]+)(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2})(\d+)$', x)[0]
    print(' '.join(parts))
```

This prints:

```
ADANIENT 29APR21 1120
AARTIIND 29APR21 1360
ADANIPORTS 29APR21 730
```

The regex used here says to match:

```regex
^
([A-Z]+)              stock name in all caps
(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2})  2 digit day, 3 letter all caps month, 2 digit year
(\d+)                 integer price
$
```